# C_c(R^n,R^m) dense in L^1(R^n,R^m)

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is the same true for functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$?
That is is $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$?

Comment: The same proof should go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes since if you consider that fact that if $ F\in C_c(\mathbb {R^n},\mathbb {R^m})$ then $F=( f_1,...,f_m)$ where $ f_i\in C_c(\mathbb {R^n},\mathbb {R}),\forall i=1,...,m$.

Then since $C_c(\mathbb {R^n},\mathbb {R})$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb {R})$, $\forall g\in L^1(\mathbb {R}),\forall \epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $ f\in C_c(\mathbb {R^n},\mathbb {R})$ such that $\|f-g\|\lt \epsilon$.

Thus the same holds for higher (finite) dimensions.